# Netbeans QuickSearch Result to Lookup

Tags: netbeans, lookup

Well, I'd like to provide QuickSearch result inside application, and, of course, through the lookup.
Searching works well, but found result is not visible through global lookup.

Can someone help to overcome this issue ?

Here is th code for a quicksearch :

```
public class QSERSCompany implements SearchProvider {

@Override
public void evaluate(SearchRequest request, SearchResponse response) {
    try {
        for (Company k : queries.ERSQuery.allCompanies()) {

            if (k.getCompanyName().toLowerCase().contains(request.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                if (!response.addResult(new SearchResult(k), k.getCompanyName())) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    }
}

private static class SearchResult implements Runnable, Lookup.Provider {

    private final Company company;
    private final InstanceContent ic = new InstanceContent();
    private final Lookup lookup = new AbstractLookup(ic);

    public SearchResult(Company c) {
        this.company= c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ic.add(company);

        try {
            StatusDisplayer.getDefault().setStatusText(
                    company.getCompanyName()
                    + ", " + company.getAddress()
                    + ", " + company.getCity());
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Lookup getLookup() {
        return lookup;
    }
}
```

}

And this is partof the code which listens for a Company object :

```
public final class ManagementPodatakaTopComponent extends TopComponent {    
   private Lookup.Result<Company> companyLookup = null;
   ...
   private Company selectedCompany;

   ...

@Override
public void componentOpened() {
    companyLookup = Utilities.actionsGlobalContext().lookupResult(Company.class);
    companyLookup .addLookupListener(new LookupListener() {

        @Override
        public void resultChanged(LookupEvent le) {
            Lookup.Result k = (Lookup.Result) le.getSource();
            Collection<Company> cs = k.allInstances();

            for (Company k1 : cs) {
                selectedCompany = k1;
            }

            setCompanyTextFields(selectedCompany);

            jTP_DataManagement.setVisible(true);
            jPanel_Entiteti.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A SearchResult which provides a lookup? Never seen this in the wild.

Please ask at nbdev@netbeans.org to get better feedback (probably from one of the NB devs)

Comment: Hello !
Well the idea is pretty straightforward from the NB point of view : to make loosely coupled architecture.
So, when I search something, I want to publish it through lookup, so components which listen will receive that data from lookup.
That's all I need, and don't know how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed somehow to get what I want :

First off, define interface:

```
public interface ICodes {
     public Code getCode();
}
```

Then, we implement quick search :

```
@ServiceProvider(service = ICodes.class)
public class ClientServicesQS implements SearchProvider, ICodes {

        private static Code code = null;

        @Override
        public void evaluate(SearchRequest request, SearchResponse response) {

            try {
                for (Code c : INFSYS.queries.INFSistemQuery.ByersByName(request.getText())) {
                    if (!response.addResult(new SearchResult(c),
                            c.getName() + " ,Code: " + c.getByerCode()
                            + (c.getAddress() != null ? ", " + c.getAddress() : ""))) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                StatusDisplayer.getDefault().setStatusText("Error." + npe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Code getCode() {
            return ClientServicesQS.sifra;
        }

        private static class SearchResult implements Runnable {

            private final Code code;

            public SearchResult(Code code) {
                this.code= code;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ClientServicesQS.code= this.code;
                    OpenTopComponent("ClientServicesTopComponent");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Display.messageBaloon("Error.", e.toString() + ", " + e.getMessage(), Display.TYPE_MESSAGE.ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, we implement lookup in other module through platform.
Because I want to call lookup whenever componentOpen, oe componentActivated is invoked, it is usefull first to define :

```
    private void QSCodeSearch() {
            try {
                ICode ic= Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ICode.class);

                if ((code = ic.getCode()) != null) {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    // setup UI components with data from lookup
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

And when topcomponent is activated, we call QSCodeSearch() in :

```
@Override
public void componentOpened() {
   ...
    QSCodeSearch()
   ...
}

...

@Override
public void requestActive() {
   ...
    QSCodeSearch()
   ...
}
```